# What vivid verb should I use when someone "turns into" a zombie?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, collocation

In conversation, when someone says they appreciate my brain, I need an effective comeback. I was going to say:

> "I hope that you are not turning into a zombie with your love for my brain."

But I feel that *"turning into"* is not a sufficiently **vivid** verb to use.

What verb should I use when someone turns into (or possibly might turn into) a zombie?

I want the verb to tell a bit of the story by describing the what and why of zombies.

Comment: It's not much more vivid than your original wording, but you could try _becoming_: _I hope you're not **becoming** a zombie_. If something more dramatic is a must: _I hope you're not **morphing** into a zombie_.

Comment: morphing has a more arty and comic aspect to it I feel. Or maybe I am just tainted by the Tony Hart art series.

Comment: Good ideas. I would upvote morphing. "Becoming" is kind of bland, like "turning into" for me.

Comment: Answer: You should use an **Inchoative** /ɪn'koətɪv/ predicate. All the predicates in all the answers below are inchoative, in that they refer to a change of state, which is often the beginning or ending of some action, event, or process. For pure change, _come to be_ (source of _become_ and still grammatical) is the idiom. For modulated change, _morph (into)_ has a modern ring.

Comment: "RUN!" would do nicely.

Comment: They use the verb "turn" in The Walking Dead.  Example: `When he turns, we'll all be in danger!`

Comment: @Flimzy The elision via intransitivity adds suspense. I like that.

Comment: _turn into a brain-eating zombie_ is vivid enough for me

Answer (score 18):

OED has a first citation from *NY Times, 1950* for...

> **zombify**: *to transform into a zombie.*

...so I don't see why in OP's context he shouldn't say...

> *"I hope that you're not being/becoming **zombified** by your love of my brain."*

Comment: My coworker suggested zombify, but I didn't find it a believable phrase. The OED's citation convinces me.

Comment: @Matthew: Well, Google Books says it has [over 8000 written instances of **"zombified"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zombified%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and I personally would say something is "a word" *if many people use it, expecting to be understood*, rather than *if it's in a dictionary*. But in this case both approaches agree, so you don't have to specifically side with either dictionaries or usage.

Comment: I agree that something is a word if many people use it, expecting to be understood.

Comment: So is it the expectation of being understood that’s crucial here, or is it the understanding itself?

Comment: @tchrist: As [any fule kno](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/any_fule_kno), only a fool would [underestimate the predictability of stupidity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQKUXDB27Dg). But I'd have to say that piously hoping *all* native speakers will understand *all* your possible utterances would be mega-foolish. Realistically, the *expectation* of being understood is far more vital to communication than the *actuality* in any specific circumstance - and if the other person isn't likely to even *know* your word, it's often pretty pointless using it (unless you're a teacher, of course! :)

Comment: I suspect that _zombify_ is always a transitive verb, and the original context calls for intransitive. Your rephrasing doesn't quite work for me – love of brains doesn't cause zombification, it's the other way around – but this could work instead: “I hope your love of my brains doesn't mean you've been zombified!” (+1 regardless.)

Comment: @Bradd: I don't understand. I grant you that intransitive use *("I zombify when I admire OP's wonderful brain")* is a little unlikely. But what has that to do with you suggesting my example *"...you're not being zombified"* somehow "doesn't work". And why would your *"you've **been** zombified"* be any better?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant that “zombified by your love of my brain” suggests that the love of brains **caused** the zombification, but that's not how it works in zombie lore. My rephrasing rearranges it so that you can infer “you've been zombified [by a zombie].” (Now if we were talking about wendigo, then love of brains could totally result in wendigolfication.)

Comment: @Bradd: I think you're trying to impose too rigid an interpretation on the possible usages. If you check out the link in my first comment, you'll find plenty of examples where people are *zombified* ***with*** or ***by*** activities, circumstances, etc. Zombie lore (law?!) notwithstanding, zombies aren't the *only* things that can "transform one into a zombie".

Answer (score 10):

How about ***[transmogrify](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmogrify)***?

> to change or alter greatly and often with grotesque or humorous effect

Comment: I remember when I was young I thought the word *transmogrify* was made up by Bill Watterson!

Answer (score 9):

"Mutate" seems appropriate to me.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is anything wrong with saying *turn*, in this context. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/turn_4 , which has the following definition of the word: **to (cause to) become, change into, or come to be something**. It's good enough for zombie films and television programmes, where characters talk of other people who have *turned*, meaning that they became a zombie.

Comment: Thank you, Tristan. Your use of "turned" with that background helps me.

Comment: Tristan, I still like your answer, but I still feel like "turned" is not vivid enough. I prefer "mutate" because of its connections to nuclear radiation, which I believe is where zombies came from.

Comment: My original question has "vivid" as the main criteria for what I am looking for.

Comment: Matthew, this question is an example of something that exists in language use, which is that in many situations, it is possible to have more than one way of saying or writing something, without changing the meaning. In such situations, it does not always matter which way is chosen.

Comment: Matthew, where zombies come from varies in fiction. Different stories have different explanations for them. Regarding the word *turn*, I remember it being used in the zombie programme called **The Walking Dead**.

Comment: Tristan, good point. What are some of the different explanations for the rise of zombies? I like *turn*, but I feel it is more vivid when used intransitively.

Comment: One of them was an artificial virus, created by scientists working for a big corporation.

Answer (score 2):

A few words come to mind:

- transform
- convert
- evolve
- devolve
- grow
- mature
- adapt

Comment: Someone who *matures* or *evolves* into a zombie isn't starting from a very good place -- those words generally connote a positive change. *Devolves* would be a better choice to describe most people undergoing zombification, although there are certainly exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

'Mutated' as suggested by Wesley Wiser would be my first choice, but 'Morphed' could also work.

- [Morphed](http://gog.is/define+morphed) - undergo or cause to undergo a gradual process of transformation.

> "He morphed into a Zombie."

Comment: I've only just seen the comments at the top, but I'm leaving it up as another option.

Comment: I always understood *morph* as specifically referring to a change in shape.  Since a zombie is (roughly) the same shape as a human, I wouldn't think *morph* would fit here.

Answer (score 1):

Morphing had already been mentioned, but one can also try to metamorphose into zombie (just the same as larva metamorphose into butterflies).

Freedictionary had got a suitable usage example: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metamorphose

Answer (score 1):

A more vivid verb that describes the what and why of zombies. Ambitious!

O.K. How about **transmute**? That hasn't been suggested by anyone yet.

Looking into the history of transmutation, I discovered that the word was used in the 19th century several years before the advent of Charles Darwin's theory of evolution: *On The Origin of Species* in 1859. Previously to that, it had been adopted by alchemists to describe the transformation of ordinary metal into gold. The promoter of the transmutation theory, the Frenchman, Jean-Baptiste Lamarck and author of *Philosophie Zoologique* (1809) claimed...

> that simple forms of life were created continuously by
>   *spontaneous generation*. He also believed that an innate life force,
>   which he sometimes described as a nervous fluid, **drove species to
>   become more complex over time**, advancing up a linear ladder of
>   complexity that was related to the great chain of being.

[Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=transmute) has this to say

*(v.) early 15c., from Latin transmutare, "change from one condition to another,"from trans-"thoroughly" + mutare "to change" Related: Transmuted; transmuting*

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'descending'. 'I hope you are not descending into a zombie'.

Answer (score 0):

Why, when you tell me, "I love you for your brain." Do I only feel fear? Fear, like, seriously? Have you undergone zombification[1]?

[1] http://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2012/10/zombies-voodoo-and-pufferfish.html

Answer (score 0):

**zombie**

'I hope your are not **zombieing**' <= **to zombie**, inchoat, *to become a zombie*

To me zombify is a causative, appropriate when you cause someone else to become a zombie.

source: [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zombieing)

Answer (score 0):

Undergoing [zombification](https://www.google.com/search?q=zombification&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is quite popular, however some prefer the slightly higher-browed term [zombifaction](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=S35&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=zombifaction&oq=zombifaction&gs_l=serp.12..0i10j0i7i30j0i10l8.7162.7162.0.10261.1.1.0.0.0.0.541.541.5-1.1.0....0...1c..31.serp..0.1.541.54K5tsx_pAk).